# Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. with changed link to public for the manifest

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I tried everything which i found in google and still the same error.
This happened after i made my vuejs project PWA.

**/public/index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
        <link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            <strong
                >We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please
                enable it to continue.</strong
            >
        </noscript>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "We do web",
    "short_name": "Wedoweb",
    "description": "Awesome app that will help you achieve your dreams.",
    "theme_color": "#fff",
    "background_color": "#333333",
    "display": "standalone",
    "icons": [
        { "src": "/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png", "sizes": "60x60", "type": "image/png" },
        { "src": "/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png", "sizes": "120x120", "type": "image/png" },
        { "src": "/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png", "sizes": "76x76", "type": "image/png" },
        { "src": "/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png", "sizes": "152x152", "type": "image/png" },
        { "src": "/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png", "sizes": "180x180", "type": "image/png" },
        { "src": "/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png", "sizes": "192x192", "type": "image/png" },
        { "src": "/img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png", "sizes": "512x512", "type": "image/png" }
    ]
}
```

I checked the with software for typo but nothing comes up.

Comment: Can you open the manifest.json in notepad? or notepad++ many editors put binary information into the file, (often the beginning IE column 1), making it no longer an ascii text file

Comment: all looks good in notepad++

Comment: try going to the url in the browser with the inspection tools open. Then look at the network tab > header tab. What is the content-type: ? application/json is what we want to see although other types are in use. Also look at the preview to see if what the server is delivering is correct.

Comment: And which browser are you using?

Comment: I just deleted the url from index html and all works good right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is teh default manifest file generated by the vue-pwa plugin

```
{
"name": "client",
"short_name": "client",
"theme_color": "#4DBA87",
"icons": [
    { "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png", "sizes": "192x192", "type": "image/png" },
    { "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png", "sizes": "512x512", "type": "image/png" },
    {
        "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-maskable-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-maskable-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    }
],
"start_url": ".",
"display": "standalone",
"background_color": "#000000"
```

}

For sure you are missing the "start_url": "." part, so try adding it, or replace teh entire thing and see if it works, then start replacing with your custom settings step by step.